# How to Compile HTML String inside foreach loop

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, compilation, directive

I am trying to compile HTML String directive which is place inside foreach loop. I even tried putting scope but still not working. My sample code looks like this:

```
hotelierApp.directive('maps', ['$translate', '$filter', '$compile',
function ($translate, $filter, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        _.each(scope.properties, function (property) {                    
                    var strHtml = $compile('<div><div class=\'hotelMarker\'>' +
                        '<div class=\'hotelIcon\'>' +
                        '<img alt=\'\' class=\'menuShadow\' src=\'{{PropertyThumbnail}}\' height=\'45\' width=\'45\'/>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class=\'hotelText\'>' +
                        '<span class=\'hotelHeader\'>{{PropertyName}}&nbsp;' +                            
                        '</span>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div></div>')(property);
                    return function () {
                        if (infoWindow) {
                            infoWindow.close();
                        }
                        infoWindow.setContent(strHtml[0].innerHTML);
                        infoWindow.open(map, markerOtherHotel, strHtml[0].innerHTML);
                    }
                })(markerOtherHotel, property.PropertyID));
            });                            
    },
    template: ''
}}]);
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

`property` is not a [scope object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) and cannot be used with `$compile` in this way. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
var strHtml = $compile('<div><div class=\'hotelMarker\'>' +
            '<div class=\'hotelIcon\'>' +
            '<img alt=\'\' class=\'menuShadow\' src=\'' + property.PropertyThumbnail + '\'' +
            ' height=\'45\' width=\'45\'/>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class=\'hotelText\'>' +
            '<span class=\'hotelHeader\'>' + property.PropertyName + '&nbsp;' +
            '</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div></div>')(scope);
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vJCHyqYLasz9qISutx3j?p=preview) for a working example.